# Grep condition not matching up correctly when it seemingly should be

Tags: shell, grep

I'm trying to create a bash script which greps through 2 files: my root package-lock.json file and one in an e2e subfolder.

I want the script to show me the amount of strings it has found which start with `"resolved": "http`

I want each of those strings to then be checked to ensure that they start with `"resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo`

This is what I've got:

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT_LOCKFILE="../package-lock.json"
E2E_LOCKFILE="../e2e/package-lock.json"

matches=$(grep '^ *"resolved": "http' "$ROOT_LOCKFILE" "$E2E_LOCKFILE")
echo "$matches" | wc -l

if [[ $matches == '"resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo'* ]]; then
  echo "All strings start with \"resolved\": \"https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo"
  echo 0
else
  echo "Not all strings start with \"resolved\": \"https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo"
  exit 1
fi
```

The `echo "$matches" | wc -l` gives me a number, which I have confirmed is correct by searching for `"resolved": "http` references in Visual Studio manually for those 2 files.

When I extend that search on VS to be `"resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo`, I get the exact same number.

So that tells me that all references which have `"resolved": "http` also start with `"resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo`

But my script enters the `else` statement, instead of working as I expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to have no matches *at all*? If that happens, is it ok, or an error?

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
[[ $matches == '"resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo'* ]]
```

is true (exit code zero), if the variable `matches` starts with

```
"resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo
```

In particular, the first character of `matches` must be a double quote character.

However, in your `grep` command, you pass to `grep` two filenames. In this case, each line of *grep* will start with the name of the matching file. Therefore this condition will fail.

You could get rid of the filenames, by using the option `-h`, but even then it is not guaranteed to work. After all, your grep pattern starts with `^ *`, and this means that a matching line could well have a space at the start, which is also different to a double quote.

Actually, your code tells me that you are only interested in two things:

```
- How many matches do we have?
- Produce a message dependend on whether the number of  matches is 0 or non-zero
```

I would translate this directly into the code:

```
nmatches=$(cat  "$ROOT_LOCKFILE" "$E2E_LOCKFILE"|grep -c '^ *"resolved": "http')

if ((nmatches > 0))
then
  echo we have matches
else
  echo no match
fi
```

Note that I use `cat` so that grep sees the input as one piece of text and `-c` calculates the total number of matching lines. This corresponds your usage of `wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

If *all* you want to do is make sure *none* of the matches were any value *other than the one you expect*, then this is simple -

```
if grep -Pq '[[:space:]]*"resolved": "http(?!s://nexus.com/repository/myrepo)' "$ROOT_LOCKFILE" "$E2E_LOCKFILE"
then echo 'Not all strings start with "resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo"
     exit 1
fi
```

This can be misleading if there were no positive hits, though.

If you need to verify that there were valid hits on the string you *do* expect, it needs an extra step or two.

```
matches=$( grep '[[:space:]]*"resolved": "http'  "$ROOT_LOCKFILE" "$E2E_LOCKFILE" )

if   grep -Pq '[[:space:]]*"resolved": "http(?!s://nexus.com/repository/myrepo")' <<< "$matches"
then echo 'Not all strings start with "resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo"'
     exit 1
elif grep '[[:space:]]*"resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo"' <<< "$matches"
then echo 'All strings start with "resolved": "https://nexus.com/repository/myrepo"'
     echo 0
else echo "There were no matches!"
     exit 1
fi
```

The pre-grep into `matches` could be skipped if these are reasonably small files, but if they are of any significant size, it's probably better to throw your result set into a string or a temp file, so I kept it.